# Looking for Tutorials/Resources to analyze cognitive experiments data

Tags: cognitive-psychology

I'm analyzing a dataset which has Go/No Go, Wisconsin Card Sorting, Stroop task. I wanted to know if there is a tutorial that follows a "best-practice" way of analyzing data. Like for statistics (e.g., t-test, ANOVA) there are step-by-step tutorials that we can follow? Is there something similar for analyzing cognitive science data?

Comment: What do you want to investigate? What are your hypotheses? You could use many types of statistical tests to analyze the data, including ANOVA and t-tests, but it's all dependent on what exactly it is you want to investigate.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I am looking to investigate go-no go. The question isn't so much about the statistics or data analysis but data compilation. How do I *aggregate* the raw data from go-nogo experiment?